# Why indexPath can change after a URLSessionTask finishes?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

I am learning ios coding and reading a book. There is something about the indexPath of a UICollectionViewCell that I don't understand. The UICollectionView displays images that are fetched using the remoteUrl attribute of the Photo Object with URLSessionDataTask. An escaping compeletion handler is passed to the image-fetching function to update the UIImageView inside the cell.

The comment of the code snippet on the book says that "*The index path for the photo might have changed between the time the request started and finished*". Why does that happen?

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let photo = photoDataSource.photos[indexPath.row]
    
    // Download the image data, which could take some time
    photoStore.fetchImage(photo: photo) { (result) in
        
        // The index path for the photo might have changed between the
        // time the request started and finished, so find the most
        // recent index path
        guard
            let photoIndex = self.photoDataSource.photos.firstIndex(of: photo),
            case let .success(image) = result
        else {
            return
        }
        
        let photoIndexPath = IndexPath(row: photoIndex, section: 0)
        
        // When the request finishes, only update the cell if it's still visible
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: photoIndexPath) as? PhotoCollectionViewCell {
            cell.updateImage(image: image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the concept of reuse of `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`. Cells are reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about reuse cell for [tableView](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse), or for [collectionView](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uicollectionview-reuse)

Example:
add code
In `viewDidLoad`:

```
collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Your Reuse Identifier")
```

In `Extension` of your viewController (UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Your Reuse Identifier", for: indexPath)
    cell.imageView.image = photos[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```